# PDF file not opening from java code

Tags: java, pdf

From java code I am able to open Text, JPEG files but for PDF file getting error

> There was an error opening this document. This file is already open or in use by another application.

Code as below :

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                try {
                    File myFile = new File(filename);
                    if(myFile.exists() && myFile.isFile())
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    // no application registered for PDFs
                }
            }
```

Note : Same file is opening from Adobe Reader.
Using Java7, Tomcat7 and Adobe Reader XI

Comment: Make sure the file is not already open. Kill Adobe Reader. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Close any other application that may be using be using the file, such as Adobe Reader, as that error pretty clearly suggests it is open and in use by something else.

Comment: I already checked whether file is in used by other application or not. Even checked processes from task manager.

Comment: I fixed the problem. One of FileOutputStream object was not closed.